# Underscorejs removing unwanted spaces for logic part

Tags: underscore.js, templating

I have an Underscore template which has if/else conditions

PROBLEM :

Underscore is inserting unwanted spaces for the logic part.
The result of the generated HTML when else condition is satisfied is

```
<a>NAME</a>


<a class="name" href="/kkk/213">kkkkkkkk</a>Sir
```

but I want an output of

```
<a>NAME</a><a class="name" href="/kkk/213">kkkkkkkk</a>Sir
```

I want to remove the line feed/space that is being inserted in the template....

Is there any solution to do this?

Comment: What does the Underscore template look like?

Comment: <a>NAME</a>
<% if(some_condition) { %>
    <%print('yours')%>
<% } else { %>
    <a class="name" href="/kkk/<%-ID %>"><%-print(NAME)%></a>
<% }%>

Answer (score 4):

Underscore's `_.template` doesn't do anything to whitespace so you have to arrange the whitespace in your template to match the output you need. Something like this:

```
<a>NAME</a><% if(some_condition) { %> yours <% } else { %> <a class="name" href="/kkk/<%- ID %>"><%= NAME %></a> <% }%>
```

Demo (look in your console): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gbx3M/

Or the more readable:

```
<a>NAME</a><%
if(some_condition) {
    %> yours <%
} else {
    %> <a class="name" href="/kkk/<%- ID %>"><%= NAME %></a> <%
} %>
```

Demo (look in your console): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/xuxLQ/

If you really need no space between the tags at all then I think you're stuck with this:

```
<% if(some_condition) {
    %><a>NAME</a>yours<%
} else {
    %><a>NAME<a class="name" href="/kkk/<%- ID %>"><%= NAME %></a><%
} %>
```

and manually stripping off leading/trailing whitespace: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LN7eU/

Another option is to use CSS to float and position the elements so that the whitespace becomes irrelevant.

If none of those options are good enough then Underscore's (intentionally) simple and minimal templates might not be for you.

Comment: @user1244197: If this solution solved your problem you should consider marking it as accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I also found that you can get rid of this unwanted whitespace by tweaking the regular expression that Underscore uses to evaluate javascript code.

```
_.templateSettings.evaluate = /(?:\n\s*<%|<%)([\s\S]+?)%>/g
```

Comment: Overriding evaluate won't help since the trim will be only in <% ... %> and no between html tags.

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded it by using a forked version of tpl.js: https://github.com/ZeeAgency/requirejs-tpl
You can find my version here: https://github.com/GuillaumeCisco/requirejs-tpl/

Basically I add a `.replace(/\s\s+/g, '')` when I receive the data, allowing me to trim spaces between tags by default.